# Laravel: How to create a hasManyThrough polymorphic Many-to-Many relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-5.7

**Situation**

I have the following **models**:

- `Post`
- `Video`
- `Tag`

These are stored in the **database tables**:

- `posts` (having `id` and `name` columns)
- `videos` (having `id` and `name` columns)
- `tags` (having `id` and `name` columns)

And also a table `taggables` with the columns:

- `tag_id` (The ID of the `Tag`)
- `taggable_id` (The ID of the `Post` or `Video`)
- `taggable_type` (Either `App\Post` or `App\Video`)

Both `Post` and `Video` models have a `morphToMany` **relationship** to `Tag`, using:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
}
```

And the `Tag` model has the inverse `morphedByMany` **relationships** set with:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Post', 'taggable');
}

public function videos()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Video', 'taggable');
}
```

(So far, this works and it is all exactly as described in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations).)

Now, in addition to this, I have a `TagGroup` model that has a `One-to-Many` relation with `Tag`, so multiple tags can belong to a tag group. (With `hasMany('App\Tag')` and `belongsTo('App\TagGroup')` using a `tag_group_id` column in the `tags` table.)

**Question**

How can I set-up a relationship between the `TagGroup` model and the `Post` and (seperately) `Video` models? (For example, to get all posts that have been tagged with tags of a certain group.)

I know there is `hasManyThrough`, but that doesn't seem to work with Many-to-Many Polymorphic relationships as the intermediate. Or am I doing something wrong?

There’s also defining custom intermediate tables with `MorphPivot` and `->using()`, but the docs are very unclear about that.

Can this be done *without* any extra plugins/frameworks?

Comment: As there is no built-in for `hasManyThrough` of many-to-many relations, there is, as far as I am aware of, also no built-in for such polymorphic relations. You can clearly create some methods to load the models of tag groups, but you most likely won't profit from eager loading...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but I have this setup

**Campaigns** --(morphedByMany)--> **Articles** --(HasMany)--> **Tags**

The pivot table (model_campaign) linking campaign and articles has the following structure:

model_id | model_type | campaign_id

I got the relationship method to work like this:

```
class Campaign extends Model
{
    public function tags(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this
            ->hasManyThrough(Tag::class, Article::class, 'model_campaign.campaign_id')
            ->join('model_campaign', function ($join) {
                $join
                    ->on('model_campaign.model_id', '=', 'articles.id')
                    ->where('model_campaign.model_type', Article::class);
            });
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it in detail yet, but on first glance this seems to be working fine